# passing array in different method

Tags: c#, arrays, methods, parameters

This is part of my code. I am getting the error "the best overloaded method match for has some invalid arguments" in my Ave method. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Thanks.

```
static void Main()
{

    string inFile="marks2D.txt";
    StreamReader sr=new StreamReader(inFile);

    int[,] marks= new int[5,6];
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        string line=sr.ReadLine();
        temp=line.Split(',');

        for(int j=0; j<6; j++)
        {
            marks[i,j]=int.Parse(temp[j]);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", marks[i,j]);
        }
    }
    Ave(marks[,], sr);
}

static void Ave(StreamReader sue, int[,] temp)
{...}
```

Comment: Parameters need to be in the right order, and you don't specify `[,]` after the variable name. So in other words: `Ave(sr, marks);`

Answer (score 2):

The parameters in the method call are in the wrong order, they need to match the order in the method declaration.

Try:
`Ave(sr, marks[,]);`